# How to get Stripe token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am setting up my app with stripe and I am having a horrible time ha. 
I finally realized that my token is returning nil. 
The error on my logs is

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RqCVc9YMVLA4pQ1DkOyfw4c0+1Fvohq/TLCxkBl/dQJLKOdvdutHv65A6xU7c2m/f262JhP2h5knhSAcZoz6/w==", "order"=>{"address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""}, "listing_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (9.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Listing Load (11.4ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
TOKEN IS:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1474ms (ActiveRecord: 22.8ms)
```

I have printed out my token which is returning nil. Which in turn is giving me a Must provide source or customer. Error. My heroku logs say the same thing. My app is here (https://abound.herokuapp.com/listings/16/orders/new)

```
def create 
      @order = Order.new(order_params) 
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id]) 
      @seller = @listing.user 

      @order.listing_id = @listing.id 
      @order.buyer_id = current_user.id 
      @order.seller_id = @seller.id 
      require "stripe"
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken] 
  logger.debug "TOKEN IS: #{token}" 

      begin 
>>ERROR      charge = Stripe::Charge.create( 
          :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor, 
          :currency => "usd", 
          :source => token, 
        ) 
        flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!" 
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e 
        flash[:danger] = e.message 
      end 
      respond_to do |format| 
        if @order.save 
          format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thanks for ordering!" } 
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order } 
        else 
          format.html { render action: 'new' } 
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
        end 
      end 
    end
```

The docs say the format should be

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_wCVovzzFUCYefEcIDpnCzcNq"

Stripe::Charge.create(
  :amount => 2000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => "tok_1A4KM1LAntdwOYiPJCq8tGRn", # obtained with Stripe.js
  :description => "Charge for abigail.miller@example.com"
)
```

Comment: How are you getting the token? Usually it's done with an AJAX call and then submitted as part of the form once the response from Stripe comes back.

Comment: Are you using Stripe Checkout? I couldn't check on your site as it requires login/signup...

Comment: @ellitt This is how I am verifying account info. I will look more into AJAX.

Comment: @jeremie yes I am using the stripe gem.

Comment: So are you getting an alert that displays the token when you submit the form? ```handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)```

Comment: @elitt 
TOKEN IS:           
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2280ms (ActiveRecord: 35.7ms)



Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Must provide source or customer.):

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:35:in `create'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code here. I did not put quotes around my keys, this was causing the token to be nil. Also, I put this 
source 'https://code.stripe.com'
On top of my gemfile.